# Capture AJAX Call

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox-addon

I am developing a Firefox add-on. It basically parses the HTML document after it loads in the browser. I am able to capture events like form submission, link clicked etc. However when a HTML pages silently submits via an AJAX call and partially gets updated, I am unable to capture them - hence as such how can I trap a web page AJAX request / response in an add-on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you can try detecting the AJAX call - what you really want to detect are page modifications it seems. You can use [mutation observers](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/05/dom-mutationobserver-reacting-to-dom-changes-without-killing-browser-performance/) (introduced in Firefox 14) for that. For example:

```js
var observer = new MutationObserver(onDocumentChange);

// We are interested in elements being added/removed and text changes, not in
// attribute changes however.
var config = { attributes: false, childList: true,
               characterData: true, subtree: true };

// Start observing the content page's document
var doc = gBrowser.contentWindow.document;
observer.observe(doc, config);
```

The function `onDocumentChange` will be called whenever changes are made to the content document.

Comment: @Prakash: Then you should update Firefox ASAP - [lots of security issues have been fixed since Firefox 12](http://www.mozilla.org/security/known-vulnerabilities/firefox.html). As I said, mutation observers are supported since Firefox 14.